# What's the difference between using the inverse trick VS cholesky trick for solving generalized eigenvalue problem?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector, cholesky-decomposition

My math professor said once that solving the generalized eigenvalue problem

$$A\lambda = \lambda B v$$

There are two methods to use:

**Method #1**

Use cholesky decomposition

$$B = LL^T$$

Solve $Y$

$$AY = L$$

Take the inverse of $L^T$ and multiply it with $Y$

$$X = Y*(L^T)^{-1}$$

Then you solve the eigendecomposition

$$X\lambda = \lambda v$$

And now you found the eigenvalues $\lambda$ and the eigenvectors $v$

**Method #2**

Take the inverse of $B$ and solve the eigendecomposition

$$B^{-1}A\lambda = \lambda v$$

And now you found the eigenvalues $\lambda$ and the eigenvectors $v$

**Question:**

According to my math professor, *method #1* is much more prefered than *method #2*.

My question is: why?

Comment: Numerical stability

Comment: @user619894 How can that be?